# How to stop Android Studio Gradle from making the drawable-anydpi-v21 folder?

Tags: android, png, android-5.0-lollipop, vector-graphics

I have a library project with vector assets, layouts and shared code, we'll call it library A. I then have another library with raster assets that depends on library A, we'll call it library B. I want these raster assets to override the base library assets. However, the build tools create a drawable folder drawable-anydpi-v21 and populate it with the vector drawables from library A, overriding library B on API 21+.

Everything *should* work just as a want it to if I can stop the build tools from making the drawable-anydpi-v21. Any ideas?